# Unable to open BIOS settings

Tags: windows-7, bios

I have HP Compaq Notebook PC with compatible Windows 7 installed. I am unable to enter BIOS Settings. First I press the ESC key which opens a list.

[image].

After this I am able to first 4 options by pressing F1, F2, F7 & F9, but pressing F10 and F12 have no effect. I have to access 'BIOS Setup' to change settings but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Are you sure F10 and F12 keys work?

Comment: As @KamilMaciorowski says, make sure your F10 key is working. You can do that here: http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html Also try using an external USB keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried pressing up arrow and down arrow?

Comment: @G-Man Yes, It dont affects it

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I checked on http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html. Only my F10 and F12 keys are not working. What can I do to make them work?

Comment: @wysiwyg I will use USB keyboard as F10 & F12 keys arenot working. Thanks for the link and suggestion. Pls. suggest what can I do to make them work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> keys don't work. You can use [keyboardtester.com](http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html) to test them. You can also connect a separate USB keyboard and try to enter BIOS setup.

If the keys don't work you may stick to fully operational USB keyboard or replace your notebook keyboard with a spare.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issue on another vendors laptop being caused by the FN button being faulty/stuck and causing the F1-F12 keys that have a function mapped to them sending the corresponding function input instead of the actual F1-F12 input. They will also then fail to appear in the keyboardtester.